# Help in styling the pagination - Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, jquery

I am displaying a set of button group listed from 1 to 5, highlighting button `1` after my jQuery library has been loaded. Once the next button is clicked, i am changing the button group from 6 to 10, and would like to highlight button `8` which is not happening in my case.

**Lightning Component**

```
<aura:component >
    <ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.jQueryLib + '/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js'}" 
                  afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.afterScriptsLoaded}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="pageNumberList" type="List"/>

     <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

     <div class="slds-button-group" role="group">    
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.pageNumberList}" var="pageNum">
           <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" 
                   id="{!pageNum.value}" 
                   onclick="{!c.offsetChanged}">
                   {!pageNum.value}
           </button>
        </aura:iteration>
            <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral"            
                    onclick="{!c.nextPageClicked}">Next</button>
     </div>
</aura:component>
```

**Controller**

```
 doInit : function(component, event, helper)
    { 
        var numberList = [];
        for(var i=1;i<6;i++)
        {
            numberList.push({
                value:i
            });
        }
        component.set("v.pageNumberList", numberList);
    },
 afterScriptsLoaded:function(component, event, helper){
      jQuery("#1").removeClass("slds-button--neutral").addClass("slds-button--brand activeBlue"); 
    },
 nextPageClicked:function(component, event, helper)
    {
        var numberList = [];
        for(var i=6;i<11;i++)
        {
            numberList.push({
                value:i
            });
        }
        component.set("v.pageNumberList", numberList);

        //**This step is executing but not shown on the DOM**//
        jQuery("#8").removeClass("slds-button--neutral").addClass("slds-button--brand activeBlue");
        console.log(jQuery("#8").attr("class"));
    }
```

[image]

[image]

**Interesting fact**

`console.log` statement at the last line of code prints `slds-button--brand activeBlue`.

I understand that the `component.set` resetting my button group to its initial state, but why is my `jQuery.removeClass()` method executing but not rendering on the DOM?

Comment: Why use jQuery to do this? Lightning provides the ability to do this native: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_styles.htm

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that. Unfortunately, in-order to use `component.find`, I have to use `aura:id` and `aura:id` doesn't support expressions (only string literals). Without expressions, i cannot give unique `aura:id` for each button under `aura:iteration`.

Comment: I'd do one of two things then, dynamically create the components so you can dynamically add the aura:id or create a child component that contains everything in the iteration so you can use a static aura:id in the child component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using the built in `A` api provided by Lightning.

To add or remove a class, call something like this:

```
var element = component.find('someAuraId');
$A.util.addClass(element, 'your-class');
```

However, I can see that you would need DYNAMIC ids for this, which means you can't use `aura:id`

There is another way though - use the source list to provide the styling.

In the init method, call this:

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) { 
    var numberList = [{'value':1,'class':'slds-button--brand activeBlue'},
                      {'value':2,'class':'slds-button--neutral'},
                      {'value':3,'class':'slds-button--neutral'},
                      {'value':4,'class':'slds-button--neutral'},
                      {'value':5,'class':'slds-button--neutral'},
                      {'value':6,'class':'slds-button--neutral'}]
    component.set("v.pageNumberList", numberList);
},
```

Now remove the `afterScriptsLoaded` method, as it's all encapsulated in the init method.

In after this, your can just call a generic setter/unsetter for these classes:

```
addClassToButtons(component,index,clazz){
    var myList = component.get("v.pageNumberList");

    for(var i=0;i<myList.length;i++){
        var elem = numberList[i];
        if (elem.value == index){
          elem.class = clazz;
        }
        else {
          elem.class = "";
        }
    }
    component.set("v.pageNumberList",myList);
}
```

Then, in your iteration, just append the class to what is there:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.pageNumberList}" var="pageNum">
   <button class="{#pageNum.class + ' slds-button '}" 
       onclick="{!c.offsetChanged}">
          {#pageNum.value}
   </button>
</aura:iteration>
```

Comment: I thought this was an anti-pattern, won't doing the get/set cause a multiple items set performance issue? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/perf_warnings_iteration.htm

Comment: It will cause the list to rerender. If you were worried about performance, just use one way binding

Comment: I see you are talking about the init part - hmm good point. Still the main part of the answer is good - I will change my answer though, as I see his `afterScripsLoaded` method alters the list again - hadn't see that.

Comment: @CasparHarmer The idea of getting the class attribute from list fixed my issue. Brilliant one, thanks. Although, out of curiosity why is that `jQuery.removeClass()` is not working there? Any idea? pardon my lack of understanding on any obvious concepts here.

Comment: I'm not totally sure, to be honest. However, the Lightning Framework mediates all access to the dom, so at the most basic level, I'd say that JQuery is being blocked from accessing that item. The Framework takes all the HTML that you see replaces it - or wraps it (I am not sure on which) with it's own markup. Perhaps the fact that you were trying to modify DOM inside an `aura:iteration` meant that you were essentially in another component - and you can't modify the contents of another component. More: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_dom_access.htm